# How to print hex in python without converting to int?

Tags: python, int, hex

I have a hex array and whenever I try to print it , it prints the int value of it

my code

```
adds = [0x8048453,
0x8048459,
0x804845b,
0x804845d,
0x8048462,
0x8048465,
0x8048466,
0x8048470,
0x8048476,
0x804847c]

for line in adds:
    print line
```

output :

```
134513747
134513753
134513755
134513757
134513762
134513765
134513766
134513776
```

I know I can convert it using hex() , but my purpose is to pack it using struct , and when I pack it

```
print struct.pack("I",hex(line))
```

I get this error message

```
struct.error: cannot convert argument to integer
```

Any idea how to resolve this ?

Comment: why do you need "to pack it using `struct`" in the first place?

Comment: @AzatIbrakov Binary Exploitation

Comment: The values are of type `int`. Printing them as hex doesn't require them to be first converted via `struct`. It also looks like you're using Python 2 so you should tag your question "python-2.x".

Comment: @martineau yes, but that was me trying to debug the issue , I found out that it doesnt use my hex values when I try to pack it using struct , it uses the int values instead .

Comment: You are confusing "print representation" with value. Essentially your int is just 0 and 1. If you need to pack an integer - provide an integer howevery you want - be it as hex or octal or whatever. the function `hex()` creates a STRING - you can not pack that using "I". USe print `struct.pack("I",line)`. The _int_s you show is the "base10 system value" of your hexvalues.

Answer (score 0):

Make the elemenents strings, go from the 2nd elemenet (and it), and just convert normally. If you need more info on converting hex to dec, i recommend [This convertion video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QJW6qnfhC70)
and working it out backwards.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution ,

```
print struct.pack("I",int(hex(line),16))
```

Hope this help someone .

Comment: This is not a solution. Your `int(hex(line),16)` just uselessly converts the int to string hex representation, then back to int again. It is the same as `struct.pack("I",line)`. (Update: Oh, I see Patrick Artner has already said this).

Comment: Don't forget that `hex` is just a convenient representation for us *programmers*, because we are human. Computers have no need for `hex`.